# Laravel Base table or view not found

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, database-migration

I'm very confused, i try to find what's wrong but i don't find it..

**My migration file:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateClientProjectTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('client_project', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('client_id');
            $table->integer('project_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('client_project');
    }

}
```

First of all, i check table is created, and it is.

Then, the `route` who calls to the `controller` is this: (is prefixed by `admin`)

```
Route::post('projectsclients/postUpload', ['uses' => 'AdminController@storeProjectsClients', 'as' => 'admin.projectsclients.store']);
```

The functions looks like here:

```
$client_project = new Client_Project();
$client_project->client_id = DB::table('clients')->orderby('id','DESC')->take(1)->get();
$client_project->project_id = DB::table('projects')->orderby('id','DESC')->take(1)->get();
$client_project->save();
```

And the error:

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'web.client__projects'
>   doesn't exist

The problem is my table is `client_project` not `client__projects`.

Where i have to fix this?

Thanks a lot, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please check your Client_Project model in your table name is right or wrong

Comment: Or show your Client_Project model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be breaking up class name with `_` for one. It should be named `ClientProject`. Generally if there is a problem with the table you would edit the modal and add a

ClientProject.php

`public $table = 'client_project';`

Comment: It works, let me ask you something. Why now i get:  `General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '[{"id":40,"name":"hola","slug":"hola","priority":0,"created_at":"2017-08-03 10:47:31","updated_at":"2017-08-03 10:47:31"}]' for column 'client_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `client_project` (`client_id`,`

Comment: Not sure @LluísPuigFerrer best off posting another question to keep things separate. I would assume that client_id is set to null on your insert query but requires an integer?

Answer (score 2):

You are not following Laravel naming conventions. To solve this particular issue yo can explicitly define tabe name. In `class Client_Projects` definition add this:

```
protected $table = 'client_project';
```

But to learn about naming conventions I suggest reading related section in documents here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Comment: It was that, i forget it;) Thanks mate, let me ask you something, why get this error: ' General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '[{"id":40,"name":"hola","slug":"hola","priority":0,"created_at":"2017-08-03 10:47:31","updated_at":"2017-08-03 10:47:31"}]' for column 'client_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `client_project` (`client_id`,'

Comment: you should update your migration and add `->unsigned()` to your integer columns

Comment: If you follow their naming convention, you won't need to remember to define table name each time, and your life gets easier :)

Comment: And about the error...that's because you're assingin the whole `Client` object to client_id. `DB::table('clients')->orderby('id','DESC')->take(1)->get();` returns an object. Yo really should consider reading​ documents, you're making yourself so much trouble. You can do what you intend to do much more easier. Read about relationships, it helps you for sure.

Comment: I will do @Nima now i'm reading the laravel doc. I think i will need some help, maybe we can make a chat? If not, and you're interested, i will make questions ;)

Comment: I prefer questions on stack overflow, because they might be others' questions too :)

Comment: I just make a new question, if you want, you can access it, it's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45483809/acces-to-data-using-relationships-laravel