# Acces to data using relationships Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, relationships

i want to access to data in the function of the controller using relationships on Laravel.

I will explain first my code:

I have 3 tables, projects, client and client_project.

At this moment, client_project don't have any relationship, i just add it manually.

Now i want to use relationships on laravel, but it's a bit confusing (for me at least).

I think it's not too much important the code of projects and clients table, just have id like primary key, and some fields more.

My migration of client_project looks like here:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateClientProjectTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('client_project', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('client_id');
            $table->integer('project_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('client_project');
    }

}
```

Client_Project model looks like here:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Client_Project extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['client_id','project_id'];

public $table = 'client_project';


    public function clients()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Project');
    }
    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Client');
    }   

}
```

One client can have more than one project, but one project is only created by one client. I think relationships are declared good.

(At first, i think with relationships i don't need to make the client_project table), but i think that's a wrong idea. I want to make it with this table too.

So, now, the problem it's when i try to call on the function controller, i think i can access to data using por example:

`App\Models\Project::find(1)`, like doc of laravel says.

The function is this:

```
$client = new Client();
$client->name = $request->input("nameClient");
$client->slug = $request->input("slugClient");
$client->priority = $request->input("priorityClient");
$client->save();

$client_project = new Client_Project();
$client_project->client_id = App\Models\Client::max('id');
$client_project->project_id = App\Models\Projects::max('id');
$client_project->save();
```

The part of the client, is working. I just take the value of some inputs and i create a new one.

The problem is with $client_project. I want to make it dynamic. I create the client and the project, and my code get the last one(the bigger id), and the last one(the bigger id too) of projects.
How can i access them using relationships?
Maybe need edit migration of client_project and put some key in project_id or client_id?

If need more information, please ask it.
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You are overcomplicating things, you dont need client_project table (this type of table is used in many to many realtionships), you just nedd client_id row in your project table and make realtion betveen Client ant Project.  But if you want the thirt table too, then just make it like many to many realtionship (you do not need ClientProject model, you make relationship - many to many - in Client and Project Models).

Comment: You can get last inserted client id using $client->id. in this way if you have more then one user are inserting on same time then it goes into false value.

Comment: @Autista_z can you make an answer of how must looks my code? I think i will do it with two tables only, and adding 1 field for respective id.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your ans. You are going good way you created pivot table for client and project so you can attached as many projects to any client. Here is relationship with model.

Client Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Client extends Model
{
    public function projects() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class,'client_project');
    } 
}
```

Project model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Projects extends Model
{



    public function client() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Client::class,'client_project');
    } 


}   

?>
```

For Save project id use following way in controller method

```
    $client = new Client();
    $client->name = $request->input("nameClient");
    $client->slug = $request->input("slugClient");
    $client->priority = $request->input("priorityClient");
    $client->save();
    $project = new Project();
//include fields as per your table 

    $project->save();

    $client->projects()->attach($project->id);
```

.

Comment: Hi @Shashikant Chautan i can't do it with 2 tables, front end code is designed for 3 tables and i can't touch it. models are looking now same like when i post the answer, but i'm trying to get the id value in controller. In controller i have to create the new Client_Project. How i take the values so?

Comment: Look it was already using three tables look at the code . You are created pivot table model which does not required.

Comment: yes, sorry. So, i can do that? `$client_project = new Client_Project();
            $client_project->client_id = $client->projects()->attach($project->id);
            $client_project->save();`

Comment: Btw, i remove client_project model. But, let me ask you something. How i will add data to client_project, if i don't have model?

Comment: No you dont require to create object of client_project().

Comment: Let me make a chat with you please, sure you can help me, i'm really confused.. and then, you repost answer and i mark it up:)

Comment: Yes sure. But i dont know how to go to chat room

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150962/discussion-between-lluis-puig-ferrer-and-shashikant-chauhan).